# Задача по Python на тему вычисление

Tags: python

1. Напишите программу, которая будет принимать числа от пользователя и суммировать их, пока он не напишет слово «sum».
2. Когда пользователь напишет слово «sum», должна быть выведена сумма всех чисел и начат процесс заново.
3. Если пользователь напишет «exit» или «quit», программа должна быть завершена.

Comment: Вот что точно нельзя - это вандализировать вопрос.

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score 7):

```
sum1 = 0
while True:
    value = input('Введите данные: ')
    if value == "sum":
        print("Общая сумма: ", sum1)
        sum1 = 0
        continue
    elif value == "exit" or value == "quit":
        break
    sum1 += int(value)
```